# PHP getting "Undefined Variable and "Empty property" errors with code

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

I have reduced this error down to the smallest amount of code and it is so small, that I really feel stupid here.

I have 2 files class1.php :

```
  1 <?php
  2 class insertText{
  3         //properties
  4         protected $paragraph1='<p>this is a test paragraph</p>';
  5         protected $bigHeader='<h1>header1</h>';
  6         protected $textArray;
  7
  8         public function __construct () {
  9                 $this->$textArray = array($this->$bigHeader1, $this->$paragraph1);
 10         }
 11         public function getText(){
 12                 return $this->$textArray;
 13         }
 14 }
 15 ?>
```

and test.php:

```
1 <?php
2 include './class1.php';
3 echo "Begin\n";
4
5 $filler = new insertText();
6 echo $filler->getText();
7
8 echo "end\n";
9 ?>
```

When I run: 
    $ php text.php

```
Begin
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: bigHeader1 in class1.php on line 9
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access empty property in class1.php on line 9
```

I know that this has te be an easy answer, and I did search and search every post with either error message. I even tried moving the assignment of text to the variables to within the constructor and it dodn't work.

Comment: Where's `bigheader1`? You have referenced `paragraph1`... PEBKAC possibly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$this->textArray = array($this->bigHeader1, $this->paragraph1);
```

...instead of..

```
$this->$textArray = array($this->$bigHeader1, $this->$paragraph1);
```

i.e.: The second dollar symbol in `$this->$bigHeader1` is redundant. (You're in effect attempting to access a class element that would be defined within the `$bigHeader1` variable, as opposed to the class instance variable itself.)

Comment: Oh man, I know it had to be a stupid answer. Sorry to waste your time.

Comment: @Dano Don't worry about it - we all make such mistakes from time to time. :-)

Comment: as well, your protected var is `$bigHeader`, but you're referring to it in the constructor as `$bigHeader1` (note the `1`).

Comment: aside from the fact that I am trying to echo an array (has been changed to print_r :) )  
I am still getting the same error messages. here is the code

`code` <?php
class insertText{
       //properties
        protected $paragraph1='<p>this is a test paragraph</p>';
        protected $bigHeader1='<h1>header1</h>';
        protected $textArray;
        public function __construct () {
                $this->$textArray=array($this->bigHeader1,$this->paragraph1);
        }
        public function getText(){
                return $this->$textArray;
        }
}
?>

Comment: You've still got `$this->$textArray`, which is incorrect. Should be `$this->textArray` (no `$` on textArray)

Comment: ok it is working. Thanks. One more question how do you get the block of code to show up on the mini markup? I tried to put `code` before and after my code, but that didn't work, I tried `my code in between the backticks` and that didn't either

edit: hahah that worked in the example I just wrote above.... oh well

Comment: @Dano Backticks are just for small code snippets - if you intend the code with 4 spaces, it'll automatically convert a block. (The { } editor button does this for you.) :-)